# Flushed my routing table and internet no longer works, how to repair

Tags: networking, debian, routing, iptables

I was trying things with the routing table, wanted to delete a rule I just added and thought it was easy like with iptables and flushed the table.

Now I no longer have a connection. When I ping something I get

> connect: network is unreachable

How do I repair it? Running:

```
service NetworkManager restart
```

Doesn’t help.

Edit : Reboot helps but as soon as I connect to a VPN server with OpenVPN it destroys my connection for good and I have to reboot again.

Comment: You should probably open a new question of the actual problem: Why does your OpenVPN connection disrupt internet connectivity? For that, please include all OpenVPN configuration files (excluding any certificates and keys, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try /etc/init.d/networking restart; /etc/init.d/iptables restart  - This will restart your network and restart IPTables as well.

Note that IPTables handles firewalling but not generally routing (routing can usually be handled with "ip route" commands or the older "route" commands)

Answer (score 0):

> Reboot helps but as soon as I connect to a VPN server with OpenVPN it destroys my connection for good and I have to reboot again.

It sounds to me that you are using the VPN server as your default gateway. If yes, please remove the default gateway pointed to the VPN server. Then your internet should be recovered. To access the subnets behind the VPN server, you need to add some static route entries for them.